# Import needs to have explicit .ts if file is being imported other than from /src/lib in Sveltekit

Tags: typescript, playwright, sveltekit

I'm trying to write some tests using Playwright inside `/tests` folder.
I'd like to use some helper functions which I could put under `/tests/lib/helpers`.

- Tests throws module not found error if `.ts` extension is not explicitly specified in the import.
- If it is, on the other hand, then IDE/Eslint complains: `TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './lib/helpers/fresh-storage.js' instead`. Though the scripts are being imported, successfully compiled and are functional.

If I would be to add this helper function under `/src/lib` and import them in `/tests` there would be no problems. So I assume I should be able change some config somewhere to be able to import typescript modules from `/tests` just like I can from `/src/lib` at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias has to be set in `svelte.config.js`

```js
// svelte.config.js

const config = {
    kit: {
        ...
        alias: {
            '$tests': 'tests',
            '$tests/*': 'tests/*',
        }
    }
};
```